# What is the algorithm of the search() function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

Does any body know what the algorithm used for the `search()` function in javascript is?

```
var myRegExp = /Alex/;
var string1 = "Today John went to the store and talked with Alex.";
var matchPos1 = string1.search(myRegExp);

if(matchPos1 != -1)
    document.write("There was a match at position " + matchPos1); 
else
    document.write("There was no match in the first string");
```

[Example copied tizaq.com](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-search.php)

I need to use this function to search a text document for different string values. But I need to document what the algorithm behind this method is, and what the complexity is. Otherwise I have to write my own method that searches the text file that I have.

Comment: The detailed implementation of the regular expression engine...? Why are you asking, what do you actually want to know?

Comment: The specification for [`String#search`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.12) is probably the best thing to read.

Comment: I need to use this function to search a document for different strings. but I need to document what is the algorithm behind this method is. otherwise I have to write my own method that searches the text file that i have.

Comment: If you don't need regex, use `String.indexOf()`, which is a linear search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification says it's implemented as a regular expression match:

> 3) If Type(regexp) is Object and the value of the [[Class]] internal
>   property of regexp is "RegExp", then let rx be regexp;
>
> 4) Else, let rx be a new RegExp object created as if by the
>   expression new RegExp( regexp) where RegExp is the standard built-in
>   constructor with that name.
>
> 5) Search the value string from its beginning for an occurrence of
>   the regular expression pattern rx. Let result be a Number indicating
>   the offset within string where the pattern matched, or –1 if there was
>   no match. (...)

([Section 15.5.4.12 String.prototype.search (regexp)](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.12)).

This means your question boils down to the regex matching algorithm. But that is not in the specification either, it depends on the implementation:

> The value of the [[Match]] internal property is an implementation dependent representation of the Pattern of the RegExp object.

([Section 15.10.7 Properties of RegExp Instances](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.7)).

So, if documenting the complexity of that algorithm is really a requirement, I guess you'll have to write your own method. But keep in mind that, by doing that, you'll probably come up with something less efficient, and probably dependent on other built-in methods whose complexity is unknown (maybe even `RegExp` itself). So, can't you convince the powers that be that documenting the complexity of a built-in, implementation-dependent js method is not your job?